# Facebook developer manage_pages not work

Tags: facebook, facebook-access-token, facebook-authentication, facebook-debugger

I have a problem with the approval of manage_pages by facebook, they say What they fail to Play the pages management function, from my developer account can very well manage the pages, if I try with another account, I can not, facebook does not ask me to authorize the app for managing pages. How can I do? Why can I only see the pages?

maybe the problem is in my server, i see

mbstring

Multibyte Support   enabled
Multibyte string engine libmbfl
HTTP input encoding translation disabled
libmbfl version 1.3.2
mbstring extension makes use of "streamable kanji code filter and converter", which is distributed under the GNU Lesser General Public License version 2.1.

Comment: _Because_ it is not reviewed yet, only users with a role in the app can be asked for the permission. If you try with an account that does not have a role in the app, then this is _not supposed_ to work - that is what review _is for_. If the reviewer can not reproduce the respective functionality in your app - then you might have to describe the necessary steps better in your review notes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried with another account with administrator role, but it does not work, does not make the request to manage the pages, the app is active and not in the sandbox, only with my accountriesco to view my pages and manage them

Comment: Admin of the app, not the page, right?

Comment: Administrator is the page that the app only I who have created the application can manage the pages, the other administrator has a shared page with me, I can administer and not him. I do not understand why

Comment: A page can not be an app admin. Again: You need to test this with an account that has a _role in your app_.

Comment: I see the shared page, and he did not, why?

Comment: I tested a page with administrator role, but only I who created the app can vederela page. It depends on the approval manage_pages?

Comment: _“I tested a page with administrator role”_ – what does that even mean …? **Again:** Only users can login to your app, not pages. And if you want to ask that user for any permission that have not been approved in review yet, then that user account must have a role **in the app*.

Comment: nothing, I do not understand, maybe I'm stupid. Because with the account with which I created the facebook app developer I see all the pages? because if you give the app administrator role to another account, it does not see its pages? because those of facebook fail to understand that they must enable the management pages of my app?

Comment: Any account with a role in the app can be asked for the permission, without review. If that doesn’t work for you, then you either have an error in your coding somewhere, or you’re messing up the test somehow. Try removing the app completely from that app admin’s account, under https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications - and then try and login to the app again, and see if you get asked for the permission now.

Comment: By accessing the page that you submitted to me, with my profile, the app is authorized to review the information on my pages, the other administrator profile, does not have permission to do so. So are those of Facebook that should trigger the possibility of asking permissions for managing pages

Comment: Sorry, I am having a hard time understanding what you are trying to say.

Comment: sorry, I do not speak English very well, I only have access via the access token available on facebook developers, from my script, I can only ask the basic authorization, which could be the problem?

Comment: Again, just so we are absolutely clear on this: All user accounts you are testing this with do have a role assigned in the app, yes? // Please double-check the app id in your code - if you were using a different app id by accident, then the users might not have a role in _that_ app.

Comment: app id and app secret is right, I checked in code, all user accounts have a role, what could be your problem?

Comment: Can you show some code, how you trigger login etc.? (Not in comment, please edit the question.)

Comment: the problem is in my server, HTTP input encoding translation disabled?